# What would happen to short positions if one entity owns All the share and isn't selling?

Tags: shorting-securities

### Edit:

[The question this was closed as a "duplicate" of](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/132805/is-it-possible-to-own-more-than-100-of-outstanding-shares) while related and interesting, does not ask or answer the question I'm asking.

What it asks is what happens with regards to things like votes and dividends while there are outstanding long positions. One of the answers also covers what happens when a short squeeze forces short positions to cover when very little (but non-zero) stock is available for perchance.

Specific it doesn't cover the question of what would happens if shorts are some how *force* to cover their position when *no* stock is offered for sale.

---

### Original question:

Basically a short squeeze, but even more so.

- Person Z buys 10% of the float.
- They offer to loan it to short positions (with some sort of obligation to return it by a fixed date).
- The shot positions sell it back into the market.
- Person Z buys another 10% of the float.
- Go back to step 2
- Repeat until Z is long by >100% of the float.

At this point there can be plenty of liquidity as 90+% of the stock is in owned by people other than Z. But what happens if Z then switches to doing *nothing at all*? They just let all the loan terms expire, collecting the returned shares but refuse to sell anything. Eventually they own **all** the shares, but someone still owns them more and there are none to buy... at any price.

Granted this is 100% hypothetical and almost surely wouldn't happen in real life, but if it did... ?

---

The closest situation that I could see actually happening would be a contract denominated in a currency that no longer exists (say it was in DEM before the Euro came along) with no provisions for anything else. But in that case both parties are motivated to resolve the situation. But in the hypothetical above, the long position doesn't care.

At a guess, some court would step in and either declare the long potion to be illegal, force a sale of shares at some set price, force the long position to accept something else of value or just declare the short positions bankrupt and liquidate them.

Comment: Do the loans *have* terms? I was under the impression they didn't.

Comment: @user253751 From what little I've looked up, they can, even if not all do. But if that's not possible for some reason, all that is required for the question is a way for Z to obligate the short positions to be covered within some time interval.

Comment: Some incorrect info.  Every time Z buys 10%, he owns more of the float so  90+% of the stock cannot be owned by people other people.  There is no loan term with shorting.  Borrowers pay a daily borrow rate times the price of the shares that day (both fluctuate).  There is no obligation to return it by a fixed date.  If Z buys 100% of the float and assuming there are no other shorters, he will own 50% of the outstanding shares (total float plus synthetic long positions).

Comment: I suspect there is an issue around the term "own". I didn't know the proper term, but "can sell immediately" is the defining criteria for what I'm referring to. If I buy a share and then loan it out, I can't sell it without getting it back first. And the people who can sell, not those who can't, will drive liquidity, which is the point I was getting at

Comment: What I've read suggests that  a lender has some say in when a short position must be covered.
httpss://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/012915/how-long-can-trader-keep-short-position.asp How that influence is applied is not the point.

Comment: @RobertLongson: I found that while writing my question: that setup is the same as I'm thinking of: but with the question being different. Rather than "who has the votes" or "how does a short squeeze play out", I'm considering the case where the shorts are (somehow) obligated to cover the positions and the longs refuse to sell, even when they hold every single share.

Comment: Phil Falcone did roughly this in 2012, and was convicted of securities fraud as a result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Falcone#2012_securities_fraud_charge

Comment: @BCS - `If I buy a share and then loan it out, I can't sell it without getting it back first.` No, that is incorrect.  You can sell the shares immediately.  It is your broker's responsibility to find replacement shares.  If he can't, he 'demands' them back from the borrower and since they are non borrowable, the borrower must buy the shares to close in order to deliver them to the purchaser of your shares (or the broker does the buy in after 4 PM).

Comment: @NickAlger: interesting, though 1) I suspect the criminal charges depend on intent which is not assumed in the question 2) it sounds like in that case long position was willing to sell, just at exorbitant prices and 3) even if it would be illegal, criminal charges would likely take long enough to leave a window where the original question is still relevant. (Could you cross post that comment to https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135605/what-happens-if-a-short-position-cant-be-covered?)

Comment: @BobBaerker Good point. But a quick check suggests that directly owning stock without a broker is possible. The concept of "own" is rather fuzzy here but that really doesn't change the core question.

Comment: @BCS - I don't follow you.  Apart from insiders and possible over the counter pricate transactions between the big players, how do everyday people acquire shares without a broker?

Comment: I Googled for "can i own stock without a broker" and got a page full of "yes" (at least in some case, which it all that is needed). Besides, the players in a scenario like I'm referring to are likely *not* "everyday people". Even just using a broker that doesn't lend would be enough (e.g. accounts for investors who intend to vote shares). Furthermore, insiders (who could be legally prohibited from selling in some conditions) would be another way to construct the "zero liquidity" condition.

Comment: @BCS -Yes, you can own a stock without a broker but most  ways either indirectly involve a broker or they are extreme cases far from mainstream investing/trading. Yes, you can buy stock from a friend but how practical is that? Yes, you can buy stock in a DRIP but many of them commingle the funds and make a market purchase (via a broker) 1-2 times a month. But in most cases, you have to buy the 1st share or more from a broker in order to joining the DRIP (only a modest number of companies offer direct purchase from day one. Company stock purchase plan also works but limits you to one stock.